# MySQL insert CASE WHEN/THEN/ELSE

Tags: mysql, sql

i', trying to insert table with case statement. But it's not working at all. i'm so confused for this problem. this is my query.

```
INTO  T_Person_Phone(ID_Person, Number_Phone_Person, Piority_Phone_Person)
VALUES  ( 255893E0 ,6474748,CASE When 1 = 1  Then 'Default' END)
```

if i set value 1 then show default. it's that any wrong with my query?

anyone can help me ??

Comment: This is all wrong: `'Piority' + convert    (varchar(5),Piority)`, but I can't work out what you're actually trying to do here.

Comment: Unrelated to your actual question, but you're not storing a phone number into an integer field, are you? Because that's a bad idea. Phone numbers are like postcode: they're actually identifiers made up of numerals, not actual numbers.

Answer (score 0):

In MySQL, when you want to concatenate strings, `CONCAT()` is used.

```
CASE When 1 = 1  Then 'Default' ELSE CONCAT('Piority', Priority) END
```

'A' + 'B' means, numeric summation. 'A' is converted to 0, 'B' converted to 0' so, 'A' + 'B' = 0.

```
mysql> select 'A' + 'B';
+-----------+
| 'A' + 'B' |
+-----------+
|         0 |
+-----------+
```

BTW, where `Priority` come from?.

*priority it's just my decrale* then, I think, "'piority' + 2 = 2"

### UPDATED

your `CASE` returns string.

```
mysql> select CASE When 1 = 1  Then 'Default' END;
+-------------------------------------+
| CASE When 1 = 1  Then 'Default' END |
+-------------------------------------+
| Default                             |
+-------------------------------------+
```

and `Piority_Phone_Person` is TINYINT. tinyint can't store string. I would recommend you to convert `Piority_Phone_Person` to VARCHAR(255).

Comment: priority it's just my decrale.

Comment: okay about priority i'm understand,but what about insert case? i'm not really understand how to insert with case?

Comment: @Juraganerka what's wrong with `CASE`? would you explain in detail? data type of Piority_Phone_Person is varchar?

Comment: data type of Piority_Phone_Person is tinyint. i can't insert table with that query. it's that true about my query up there?

Comment: @Juraganerka I guess data type of Piority_Phone_Person is a problem. i have updated my answer.